# UIImage gets released at the end the function after assignment has been made

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, assign

I have a ViewController that holds a custom UIView as its member like this:  @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet ProfileUIView * profileUIView;
in my ViewController i get back a UIImage from an imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: and there i'm assigning the UIImage i get to a local UIImage variable in my ProfileUIView. i see that the UIImage variable get assigned, but, after the set function ends the UIImage variable get nil and i loose the image somehow.

here is a snippet of imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: that's in my ViewController:

```
NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage]) {

    [self.profileUIView setPicture:info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

    if (_newMedia)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.profileImage, self, @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
}
```

here is the implementation of setPicture:(UIImage *)image: inside my UIView:

```
self.profilePic = image;    
[self.pictureButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

how can i fix it?  
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ViewController.h**

Here we make sure to import the right frameworks, hold a `UIImage` and the `ProfileUIView` instance. We also declare a method to pick an image, which can be invoked, e.g., from a button on the corresponding view, when connected in Interface Builder:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#import "ProfileUIView.h"


@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *profilePic;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet ProfileUIView *profileUIView;
- (IBAction)pickImage:(id)sender;

@end
```

In **ViewController.m** we implement the method to pick an image and the delegate method that is invoked once the user has picked an image:

```
- (IBAction)pickImage:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *pickerC = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    pickerC.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:pickerC animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - UIImagePicker delegate methods
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage]) {
        self.profilePic = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        [self.profileUIView setPicture:self.profilePic];
    }
}
```

**ProfileUIView.h**

Here we declare the profile picture `UIImage`, the `UIButton` which shows the picture, and the method that sets the image:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ProfileUIView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *profilePic;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *pictureButton;

- (void) setPicture:(UIImage *)image;

@end
```

**ProfileUIView.m**

Here we make sure that the UIButton is in place when we awake from NIB, and implement the set picture method to set the image as background of the `UIButton`:

```
#import "ProfileUIView.h"

@implementation ProfileUIView

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    self.pictureButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    [self addSubview:self.pictureButton];
}

- (void) setPicture:(UIImage *)image {
    self.profilePic = image;
    [self.pictureButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

@end
```

When `pickImage` is invoked on the main `UIViewController`, it stores the image from `UIImagePicker` into the `profilePic` property on the `UIViewController` and  assigns the image using the original `setPicture` method.

Comment: ive just tried your solution. it works the same as before. the self.profilePic saves the UIImage inside the controller, but the nested view still looses it after exiting setPicture.

Comment: How did you declare the property `profilePic` inside `ProfileUIView`?

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage * profilePic;

Comment: You are using ARC, right? I'm setting this up to reproduce it.

Comment: as far as i know, i do. i'm a bit new to objective c. and thanks btw.

Comment: I set up a sample project, and it works. I'll edit my answer to show the other files, so you can check.

Comment: i appreciate the code you've added. my code is the same - i even see that self.profilePic is inited with the image passed to setPicture, but, again after it exits setPicture the self.profilePic goes to nil and image is lost. if i run the app without debugging you can actually see the image appear for few milliseconds and then goes away...

Comment: That's really strange, as `UIButton` even retains the image. You do not `nil` the image anywhere yourself, right? Also, `setPicture` is called only from this one point? Which other methods do you have in `ProfileUIView`?

Comment: no nil it anywhere at all, and yes, setPicture is called only from one place - as a reaction on click on an alertView. in ProfileUIView i also have setup function thats called from awakeFromNib - its for shaping the button as a round button. i also have method called addPictureClick which is invoked when you click the picture button and through a delegate to the controller it invokes a UIAlertView which there you click the button and a method like your pickImage: is invoked

Comment: In the `setPicture` method, can you try to set the background color instead of the image? Like so: `[self.pictureButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];`. What happens?

Comment: i've inserted your code line - i see exactly the same - for a few milliseconds it colors in red then disappear. i've placed brake points on all the functions inside my view, when debugging i see it goes to setPicture then goes out, afterwards it goes in awakeFromNib and there already the profilePic is nil..

Comment: it's like when it exits setPicture function it erases the data in the UIImage. i don't know how to go on

Comment: Ah ok, so there you have the problem! `awakeFromNib` should only be called the first time the view is loaded (in fact, in the code I've written above, it only gets called once). What happens is that your `ProfileUIView` gets loaded again, which resets everything you did. Place a breakpoint inside `awakeFromNib`. When it's hit the second time, look in the debug navigator at the left of Xcode where you'll see the call stack. This should tell you why the view is re-inited. You can also paste your complete code alternatively :)

Comment: man.... YOU ARE AWSOME! thanks a lot! you were right, it has been called every time cause inside the controller i used viewDidAppear: to init the view which called on awakeFromNib each and every time - changed it to viewDidLoad instead - now it works! thanks again:)

Comment: Glad to help :) Would be great if you could accept the answer ;)

Comment: :) Yes thanks - on Stack Overflow you can accept answers (as you did) and you can upvote answers (the up arrow next to the answer), which indicates that an answer was helpful. Usually you will do both, so the answerer gets some points ;) thanks again